# Sync Mac mini and Macbook

Tags: macos, mac

I have a Macbook and I have a Mac mini. Is it possible to have these two machine share the same environment, so that if I installed something in one I also have it on the other. They need to share the same folders, same files, same states.

What is the closest solution for this problem?